# Getting Request method 'GET' not supported - Python

Tags: python, api, python-requests

So I've been trying to request an API using the following endpoint: 
`http://viatorapi.viator.com/service/search/products?destId=684&apiKey=98765687*****`

Using the following python code:

```
import requests
import json

resp_1 = requests.get("http://viatorapi.viator.com/service/search/products?destId=684&apiKey=98765687*****")

res = resp_1.json()

print(res)
```

But I keep getting a `Request method 'GET' not supported` error even when I try the request directly from the browser.

I've been looking at the documentation for a while now and it's says that It's supposed to be a POST request.

Here: https://docs.viator.com/partner-api/affiliate/technical/#tag/Product-services/paths/~1search~1products/post

Any ideas on why this is happening and how to fix this?

**UPDATE**

Here's the new code I'm about to try:

```
import requests
import json

j="""{"destId": 684,"seoId": null,"catId": 3,"subCatId": 5318,"startDate": "2018-10-21","endDate": "2019-10-21","dealsOnly": false,"currencyCode": "EUR","topX": "1-3","sortOrder": "TOP_SELLERS"}"""

resp_1 = requests.post("http://viatorapi.viator.com/service/search/products?apiKey=98765687*****", data=json.loads(j))

res = resp_1.json()

print(res)
```

Comment: Why it would be a post when you are expecting the results back?

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer! Exactly where the problem is, I don't know why it's a POST request..

Comment: Use a program to snoop on the *actual* communication going on with the server, such as Telerik Fiddler. Then you’ll *know* what sort of request is actually being sent.

Comment: I was made aware by the Admin of the server that I'll need to use a dedicated tool such as Postman. What am I supposed to do with it?

Comment: I don't understand the question. If it wants a post, why don't you send a post?

Comment: I tried a Post request but I get a Response [415] in my cmd.

Comment: @mad_ because results can depend on the input data?

Comment: 415 means invalid media type... what type are you POSTing, vs what type is expected?

Comment: @JacobIRR The only thing I did is to change the `requests.get()` to `request.post()`

Comment: @locq you dont ever *have* to use something like postman. you can do this using the python `requests` library, or even the standard library `urllib.request`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.viator.com/partner-api/affiliate/technical/#tag/Product-services/paths/~1search~1products/post) you linked,
it is clear that it only takes POST requests for `/search/products`. Generate a json (like the sample json from the documentation) and do a post request.

```
import requests
import json

j="""{
"destId": 684,
"seoId": null,
"catId": 3,
"subCatId": 5318,
"startDate": "2018-10-21",
"endDate": "2019-10-21",
"dealsOnly": false,
"currencyCode": "EUR",
"topX": "1-3",
"sortOrder": "TOP_SELLERS"
}"""
headers={'Content-type':'application/json', 'Accept':'application/json'}
resp_1 = requests.post("http://viatorapi.viator.com/service/search/products?destId=684&apiKey=98765687*****", data=j, headers=headers)
print(resp_1.json())
```

Comment: Thanks @Ricky, I'll update the original question with what I'm about to try. Please take a look and tell me if this look okay.

Comment: @locq added an example for you

Comment: Thanks, I'll try in a sec.

Comment: I just tried the code from my updated question but I get a json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) so I'm pretty sure I'm getting the same error.

Comment: @locq try the code that I have instead? code from your updated question is wrong

Comment: Okay so I just tried but keep getting the  json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: The output I'm getting is <Response [415]> again.

Comment: @locq r u sure you copied correctly? You can run the code here: [https://repl.it/repls/ThinAwfulMonitor](https://repl.it/repls/ThinAwfulMonitor)

Comment: Yes I also just tried on the link you provided but I still get the same error:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value)from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: you can click Run on that link and see that it works

Comment: Same, when I add my own API key, I still get the same error. I know that when I try with the wrong API key I get a ['API access denied for attemptedkey ID: 98765687*****']

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197408/discussion-between-ricky-kim-and-locq).

Comment: Just use e.g. Fiddler to trace a browser interaction then make sure your code replicates the cookies/headers/content.